# How to console.log specific module + codeline in devtools instead of "main.chunk" in create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-devtools, create-react-app

I am starting a new project with create-react-app. How can I make that my devtools show the actual module + codeline when I console.log something? 
Currently iut only displays "main.chunk".

[image]

Comment: did you bundle your react application?

Comment: if you are using webpack for bundling you need to setup source maps https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/

Comment: Make sure sourcemap is enabled in your browser. When your app is created with create-react-app then sourcemaps are enabled in code already and you don't need to change webpack.config (you don't even have one unless you eject and I would not advise doing that).

Comment: @SaiYerniAkhil: Not manually, I use "create-react-app".

Comment: @HMR: Yes, I created the app with create-react-app and thus have no webpack.config.